# button click which makes attachment dialog open

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog

hey guys I am trying to send an attachment file but the attachment dialog is not opening 
but instead it is rather telling me 'input string was not in a correct formart

```
            private void proto_Type_AI_Blackhead_God(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    OpenFileDialog attachment = new OpenFileDialog();
                    attachment.InitialDirectory = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments.ToString();
                    attachment.Filter = "xml File (*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif)|*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif;|Pdf files|*.pdf;|Xml files|*.xml";
                    if (attachment.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Value)
                    {
                        filename = attachment.FileName;

                        filename = attachment.SafeFileName;                    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("seriously bad");
                    }
                    attachment = null;
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Which line causes an error? It seems, that your filter string is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that you got this code compiled.

First of all, `OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()` returns `bool?`, so have it properly checked (for `HasValue` initally and then the value of `Value`).
Then, why do you overwrite `filename` variable? I assume `filename` is some global variable here.

Further, having that fixed I had no problems running the code, filter string is perfectly correct semantically. Logically, *jpegs*, *bmps* and *gifs* are not XML files.